# What are commit-ish and tree-ish in Git?

Tags: git

### The Question

What are specific examples of commit-ish and tree-ish in Git?

The Stack Overflow question ["What does tree-ish mean in git?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4044368/456814) deals
with tree-ish specifically, but I want to understand more about ***both***.

### Background

#### Usages in Documentation

[The Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) makes several references to "commit-ish" and
"tree-ish". For example, if you're examining [the Git source code](https://github.com/git/git):

```
$ git grep --files-with-matches --extended-regexp "commit(-)*ish"
config.txt
git-describe.txt
git-fast-import.txt
git-name-rev.txt
git-push.txt
git-rebase.txt
git-rev-parse.txt
git.txt
gitcli.txt
glossary-content.txt
howto/revert-branch-rebase.txt
revisions.txt
```

and

```
$ git grep --files-with-matches --extended-regexp "tree(-)*ish" | \
$ grep --invert-match RelNotes
diff-format.txt
diff-generate-patch.txt
git-archive.txt
git-cat-file.txt
git-checkout.txt
git-diff-index.txt
git-diff-tree.txt
git-ls-files.txt
git-ls-tree.txt
git-merge-tree.txt
git-read-tree.txt
git-reset.txt
git-svn.txt
git.txt
gitcli.txt
gittutorial-2.txt
glossary-content.txt
revisions.txt
```

#### Definitions

The Git documentation [defines what "commit-ish" and "tree-ish" are](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_identifier_terminology):

> ```
> <tree>
> ```
>
> Indicates a tree object name.
>
> ```
> <commit>
> ```
>
> Indicates a commit object name.
>
> ```
> <tree-ish>
> ```
>
> Indicates a tree, commit or tag object name. A command that takes a `<tree-ish>`
>   argument ultimately wants to operate on a `<tree>` object but automatically
>   dereferences `<commit>` and `<tag>` objects that point at a `<tree>`.
>
> ```
> <commit-ish>
> ```
>
> Indicates a commit or tag object name. A command that takes a `<commit-ish>`
>   argument ultimately wants to operate on a `<commit>` object but automatically
>   dereferences `<tag>` objects that point at a `<commit>`.

### The Documentation isn't Clear Enough

Even though the documentation above defines what "commit-ish" and "tree-ish" are,
I still find it to be too vague and unclear.

**What are specific examples of "commit-ish" and "tree-ish", and how are they
different from each other?**

Comment: See also the online [gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary), or use `man gitglossary` in your CLI

Answer (score 203, accepted):

## The Short Answer (TL;DR)

Here's a complete list of commit-ish and tree-ish identifiers (from [the Git
revisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions)):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Commit-ish/Tree-ish    |                Examples
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1. <sha1>                | dae86e1950b1277e545cee180551750029cfe735
|  2. <describeOutput>      | v1.7.4.2-679-g3bee7fb
|  3. <refname>             | master, heads/master, refs/heads/master
|  4. <refname>@{<date>}    | master@{yesterday}, HEAD@{5 minutes ago}
|  5. <refname>@{<n>}       | master@{1}
|  6. @{<n>}                | @{1}
|  7. @{-<n>}               | @{-1}
|  8. <refname>@{upstream}  | master@{upstream}, @{u}
|  9. <rev>^                | HEAD^, v1.5.1^0
| 10. <rev>~<n>             | master~3
| 11. <rev>^{<type>}        | v0.99.8^{commit}
| 12. <rev>^{}              | v0.99.8^{}
| 13. <rev>^{/<text>}       | HEAD^{/fix nasty bug}
| 14. :/<text>              | :/fix nasty bug
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|       Tree-ish only       |                Examples
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 15. <rev>:<path>          | HEAD:README.txt, master:sub-directory/
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|         Tree-ish?         |                Examples
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 16. :<n>:<path>           | :0:README, :README
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Identifiers #1-14 are all "commit-ish", because they all lead to commits, but
because commits also point to directory trees, they all ultimately lead to
(sub)directory tree objects, and can therefore also be used as "tree-ish".

#15 can also be used as tree-ish when it refers to a (sub)directory, but it
can also be used to identify specific files. When it refers to files, I'm not
sure if it's still considered "tree-ish", or if acts more like "blob-ish" (Git
refers to files as "blobs").

## The Long Answer

### Commits and Directory Trees in Git

At its lowest levels, Git keeps track of source code using four fundamental
objects:

1. Annotated tags, which point to commits.
2. Commits, which point to the root directory tree of your project.
3. Trees, which are directories and subdirectories.
4. Blobs, which are files.

Each of these objects has its own sha1 hash ID, since Linus Torvalds designed
Git like an [content- addressable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_storage) filesystem, i.e. files can be retrieved
based on their content (sha1 IDs are generated from file content). The Pro Git
book gives [this example diagram](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects):

[image: Figure 9-3 from Pro Git book]

### Commit-ish vs Tree-ish

Many Git commands can accept special identifiers for commits and (sub)directory
trees:

- "Commit-ish" are identifiers that ultimately lead to a commit object. For example,

  `tag -> commit`
- "Tree-ish" are identifiers that ultimately lead to tree (i.e. directory) objects.

  `tag -> commit -> project-root-directory`

Because commit objects always point to a directory tree object (the root
directory of your project), any identifier that is "commit-ish" is, by
definition, also "tree-ish". In other words, ***any identifier that leads to a
commit object can also be used to lead to a (sub)directory tree object***.

But since directory tree objects never point to commits in Git's versioning
system, not every identifier that points to a (sub)directory tree can also be
used to point to a commit. In other words, **the set of "commit-ish" identifiers
is a strict subset of the set of "tree-ish" identifiers.**

The set of tree-ish identifiers that ***cannot be used as commit-ish*** are

1. `<rev>:<path>`, which leads ***directly*** to directory trees, not commit
   objects. For example, `HEAD:subdirectory`.
2. Sha1 identifiers of ***directory tree*** objects.

Comment: Dont' forget about `stash@{0}`. I'd like to know where that fits into all this. Are there any other things like the stash (`my-thing@{0}`)? Is the stash just a `<refname>`?

Comment: It hasn't been made clear explicitly that a tree-ish identifier seems to be a *more specific* identifier than a commit-ish identifier. Maybe I'm weird but that's the only sensible way to explain it IMO

Comment: So is `<rev>` yet another synonym for commit-ish?, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 50):

Note for non-native English [sic!] speakers: "-ish" is a suffix that can be applied to an adjective in order to indicate "having qualities like" or "slightly" - see http://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=ish&title=21st

Hence "tree-ish" - like a "tree" .... "commit-ish" - like a "commit"

eg "Mars appears like a reddish star" ("d" is doubled !); "the food on the plate was not hot, but warmish"

*I believe that this helps explain "what are ..." better, in that it explains the language usage.*

Comment: I've always interpreted "tree-ish" and "commit-ish" to be analogous to saying "Swedish" or "English". The usage you describe makes less sense to me because that form of "ish" creates an adjective. But the rev isn't "like" a tree or commit, it *is* a tree or commit. On the other hand if you think of "ish" as a language suffix then they make more sense as nouns on the command line, where "tree-ish" is the language that forms the noun. I don't know which interpretation was the intent of the authors, but that's how I've always seen it.

Comment: I see your point, but I was just giving the impression I have, as a native English speaker !

Comment: I'd tend to agree with @MikeW (albeit I'm natively a French speaker) ; while technically "commit-ish" should be an adjective, I've noticed that terms that you make up but that you often use tend to become nouns. A few months ago I used the term "bus width" often, and eventually I just started writing "buswidth" as a whole word as if it were a noun because of how familiar I became with it. Think of like Linux's `termios`, or the french expression `bon jour` ("good day"), that eventually became `bonjour`. I'm actually surprised they kept writing it `commit-ish`, and not `commitish`.

Comment: In the sense that adjectives like "tree-ish" and "commit-ish" are used as nouns, it's a form of ellipsis; they really mean "tree-like thing" and "commit-like thing". Perhaps "pseudo-tree" and "pseudo-commit" would've been more obvious terms to non-English speakers, by analogy with "pseudo-code".