# Difference between git checkout - and git checkout master

Tags: git, git-checkout

What are the differences between:

```
git checkout -
```

and

```
git checkout master
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between "git checkout - . " and "git checkout -- ."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001013/difference-between-git-checkout-and-git-checkout)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+difference+%22checkout+-%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout -
```

is just a shortcut to check out the previously checked out branch.

[Docs](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.2.txt#L85)