# checkout the first commit in the history containing a given String

Tags: git, commit

I think I have seen on twitter a way to specify a commit by providing a String that is contained in its message. So with a history like this

1. alpha <-- current head
2. beta
3. gamma
4. gamut
5. omega

`git checkout <magic stuff>'gam'` would checkout the commit with commit message `gamma`.

What was the syntax for this?

Note 1: I'm not actually sure that was for `checkout`, might have been for a different command, but I'm hoping for one that is universally applicable.

Note 2: It might not have been specifying a single commit but the range starting at that commit and ending at the current HEAD.

Comment: At least you are able to *search* the log with `git log --all --grep='gam'`

Comment: `git checkout $(git log --pretty=%H -1 --grep=gam)`. I'm not sure if it's what you have seen before.

Comment: Have you tried `git checkout :/gam` ?

Comment: @mp911de that's it. Please submit an answer so you might receive your well-earned internet karma.

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/exposure :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following form:

```
git checkout :/<term>
```

In your case it's:

```
git checkout :/gam
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23303550/2067527 for more details on the various tree-ish and commit-ish forms.