# How can I npm install private library from bonobo git server?

Tags: git, package.json, bonobo

I created library which sits under angular/dist folder and I pushed whole project to Bonobo git server.

I want to include this library in pakcage.json in Angular

Should I store only library folder (which is folder under angular/dist) on git server?
and how can I include in package.json?

Answer (score 0):

You can install from folder or git repo, following is `npm i -h`.

```
$ npm i -h

npm install (with no args, in package dir)
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version range>
npm install <alias>@npm:<name>
npm install <folder>
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <git:// url>
npm install <github username>/<github project>
```

So, this question has two solution:

**1. Install from folder**

```
git submodule add <library repo url> <folder of library>

npm i file:<folder of library>
```

**2. Install from git remote repo**

```
npm i <library repo url>
```

Or include [commit-ish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303549/what-are-commit-ish-and-tree-ish-in-git).

```
npm i <library repo url>#<commit-ish>
```