# How can I compare my local forked repository with changes that may have been made to the original?

Tags: git, github, git-diff, git-fork

I want to compare the local clone of a repository I have forked with the original/upstream repository to see if further commits have been made requiring me to pull/merge. I'd like to do this from the command line.

I added the original repository to my list of remotes with this command:

```
git remote add upstream <original repo URL>
```

This is outlined in [Github's own page on the topic of forking a branch](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/).

However, when I run `git diff upstream`  or  `git diff upstream/master` [as advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688732/1563507) or `git diff master upstream/master` [as advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801150/1563507), I get this:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

The command `git diff origin/master` does not return an error (or anything for that matter). Have I missed something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Before one can run a `git diff` between one's own local repo and the upstream, one must first fetch the upstream repo. The comparison is then made locally.

```
git fetch upstream
```

This does not affect the working branch of your repo but it does add a whole other bunch of "remote" branches, which you can see with `git branch -a`.

Once you've got those, use:

```
git diff master upstream/master
```

This will compare the local repository you have with any updates that have been made to the original repository. Variations on this command will deal with updates you may have made to your own branch or check against a common ancestor (e.g., `git diff master...upstream/master`) as usual.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to compare the local clone of a repository I have forked with the original/upstream

In May 2022, that comparison can be done online on GitHub:

> ### [Compare differences between branches](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-16-compare-differences-between-branches/)
>
> We've added an enhancement to the repository view for a branch that is different than its upstream branch.
> Previously we showed the number of commits the branch was ahead or behind the upstream, but there wasn't an easy way to show the differences.
>
> **Now you can click a link that takes you to a comparison page to see the differences**.
>
> [image: image -- https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/90000203/166960932-d630a74f-4e08-47f3-a06f-c87638b64366.png?ssl=1]
>
> Note: there is a different link for ahead versus behind
>
> - `ahead` represents changes your branch has but the upstream branch does not
> - `behind` represents changes the upstream branch has but your branch does not
>
> [Read more about branches](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-branches).