# Compare working area with remote (origin/master)

Tags: git

I've been learning about **gif diff** but I'm still confused about one thing: let's say I make some changes locally. I don't want to add/commit these changes, but I would like to see the differences between my working area and the remote repo. The point is to see the differences between my local files (my Working Area) and the remote repo (origin) before merging them. I've tried this:

```
git fetch origin master
git diff origin/master (or just "git diff origin")
```

Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: What do you mean "before merging them"? You cannot merge uncommitted changes. And you can always replace a commit with a new commit before pushing (`commit --amend`). This might be an XY problem. Why don't you want to commit (locally)?

Comment: Let's say they are changes I'm not sure about, or maybe just changes made by mistake.

On the other hand, I get it: I must commit in order to be able to merge ;)

Comment: Apparently, the same question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688594/how-to-diff-between-local-uncommitted-changes-and-origin/17688732).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the man page of [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--merge-baseltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203), you will see a list of possible ways how to call it. One of them is:

> `git diff [<options>] [--merge-base] <commit> [--] [<path>…​]`
>
> This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree relative to the named . You can use HEAD to compare it with the latest commit, or a branch name to compare with the tip of a different branch.

So, you would simply run: `git fetch; git diff origin/whatever` to compare your local worktree changes relative to the named commit.

---

But don't be afraid to create temporary, local commits:

```
git commit -am 'temp'
# now compare commit with another commit, e.g. a remote one: git fetch && git diff origin/whatever HEAD
git reset HEAD^ # roll back the temporary commit
```

---

Or, if you are okay with using plumbing commands:

```
git add -u
# git fetch
git diff origin/whatever "$(git commit-tree -m 'temp' "$(git write-tree)")"
git  reset
```

Comment: Will try this, thanks. In any case, I still don't get it: is it only possible to compare changes committed to the local repo with the remote repo (origin)? Is not possible to compare uncommited chantes with remote?

Comment: @Alfredo I have restructured my answer. `git diff` can do it, simply run `git diff origin/whatever`

Comment: I guess this makes it clear. Thank you very much.